# How to use Google Map with KeystoneJS

Tags: keystonejs

Beginner here,

I am trying to auto-fill a GeoPoint field with lat/lng information after a user finishes entering name of a city. My model looks like the following:

```
Location.add({
title: { label: 'Location name', type: String, required: true },
content: {
    product: { label: 'Product', type: Types.Select, options: 'Option1, Option2', default: 'Option1', index: true, required: true },
    address: { label: 'Address', type: String, required: true, initial: false },
    state: { label: 'State', type: Types.Select, options: usStates, index: true, required: true, initial: false},
    city: { label: 'City', type: String, required: true, initial: false},
    country: { label: 'Country', type: Types.Select, options: 'USA', default: 'USA', index: true },
    latlng: { label: 'GEO Location', type: Types.GeoPoint, enableMapsAPI: true, **watch: 'city', value: getGEO**},
    cloudinaryImages: { label: 'Location images', type: Types.CloudinaryImages },
},});
```

And I declared my getGEO function as such (nothing happens now):

```
function getGEO() {
  console.log('HELLO WORLD...')
}
```

However, when I submit the generated form the function getGEO does not get called. Need help resolving this issue. On top of that:

- I am not sure whether the model is the right place to call this function.
- How do I assign the lat/lng values to the GeoPoint field?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What version of Keystone are you using? It looks like you may be wanting a [Location](https://github.com/keystonejs/keystone/tree/master/fields/types/location) field type rather than a GeoPoint. The Location field supports geocoding lookup via the Google Maps API; a GeoPoint will require you to implement similar logic yourself.

Comment: I m using 4.0.0-beta.5. The problem with Location field type is that it displays Australian address format. Our use case is for a US address.

Comment: Also, I need to set the state and country to a dropdown. Using the Location field type I understand there is a 'default' option but it does not allow for a dropdown for state.